# Plugin JQuery nao funciona no github pages

Tags: jquery, github

Pessoal coloquei um plugin do JQuery chamado nice scroll para a pagina rolar devagar, mas quando abro a pagina no github pages ele nao funciona, o resto do script e do css estao todos funcionando menos eles, alguem sabe o porque?

Comment: coloque o endereço? já viu o debug se tem algum erro?

Comment: https://fmm312.github.io/site/ , esse é o endereço

Comment: faça o teste: coloque esse no lugar: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8/jquery.nicescroll.min.js (copie o endereço daqui https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8)

Comment: tentei cara, nada até o momento ...

Comment: Olha a resposta @blackbird312

Comment: o debug aponta 2 erros, mas sou leigo e nao sei muito bem oq é

Comment: eu acabei de ver faltou o https

Comment: Cara olha a minha resposta precisa ser daquele jeito com https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro no `debug`: *A requisição foi bloqueada porque, o link não vem de um endereço seguro*.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fmm312.github.io/site/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

precisa ser um `https` como por exemplo:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8/jquery.nicescroll.min.js
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8/zoomico.png

```
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8/jquery.nicescroll.min.js">
</script>
```

[Link - jquery.nicescroll](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.8)

Comment: resolvido, obrigado cara !